# How do i monitoring my data from my pir motion sensor to a web server?

Tags: java, python, raspberry-pi, monitoring, sensors

This is my code right now. I'm using Python. I don't know how i have to do this. So i hope you guys know :) Its for a school project so i hope you guys will help me. Please comment your answer below.

```js
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

#----Lampje
ledPin = 23
# Zet de pinmode op Broadcom SOC.
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
# Zet waarschuwingen uit.
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
# Zet de GPIO pin als uitgang.
GPIO.setup(ledPin, GPIO.OUT)

#----Bewegingssensor----
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
PIN = 26
GPIO.setup(PIN, GPIO.IN)

print "Start sensor..."
time.sleep(2)
print "Sensor activated..."

while True:
   if GPIO.input(PIN):
      print "Movement detected! " + (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
      time.sleep(0.5)
      GPIO.output(ledPin, 0)
      time.sleep(0.5)
      GPIO.output(ledPin, 1)
   time.sleep(0.1)
```